# How to insert an image directory in a postgresql table?

Tags: image, postgresql, debian

I desperately search an answer of my problem but I didn't find it yet. I would like to import an image in a table in my PostgreSQL data base.
I have already created the table with 7 fields, in three fields my goal is to put the directory of the image, like this for example: `/Images_DB/P1250420.JPG`.

My data base is stored in a server (a cloud) with the OS Debian9, my image is on the server.
But, when I look at my table linked with a geometric table, I haven't got a link to see my image.

My SQL script to create my table :

```
CREATE TABLE aerien.pj_bis
(
    id_pj bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('aerien.pj_bis_id_pj_seq'::regclass),
    num_support character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    num_support_code_lit character varying(250) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    image_support oid,
    chemin_expertise oid,
    chemin_convention oid,
    commentaire character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT pj_bis_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_pj)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

The SQL command when I try to import data into my table :

```
INSERT INTO aerien.pj_bis VALUES ('1','1','1 BASTILUCCI',lo_import('/Images_DB/P1250420.JPG'));
```

And in this image you have a view of my table after these two commands lines:

[image: Image showing the table row with the OID in it]

Comment: Looks like the large object was imported fine. Please describe what you mean by a link to see your image. Which software are you using? What is your setup?

Comment: I would like to see my image... Maybe, my image is well imported but I don't arrive to see her ! I use the client software PgAdmin to create my table and import my data into my data base. I also use QGIS to check what my data looks like. Maybe, I haven't understand well the goal of data type OID...

Comment: The OID is the number of the large object. You need to use the large object API ([here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html) is the C API, but there are others) to access the large object. Your client needs to support large objects.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answer. But I'm really sorry, I'm inexperienced in this field and It's really difficult for me to understand all this things ! So, what do you mean when you are saying : "Your client needs to support large objects.". For example, the software client QGIS can permit to see an image stored in my database... I'm really sorry If I say many foolery...

Comment: If you want to visualize a large object with QGIS, QGIS needs to support PostgreSQL large objects. You better ask the QGIS people - I have no experience with it.

Comment: Okay, but indeed I just want a link (like a an url link) and when the user clik on this link , the image, or the pdf file open... I don't know how to do this... Maybe I don't writte my question properly. Because when you speak about large object what do you mean ? Your image is all stored in the database ? Sorry, but I don't understand... :(

Comment: A link can is opened with a web browser, so you need a web server that serves the link, so you need a web application that retrieves the large object from a database so that the web server can send it to the client, right? Sorry, but this is becoming too broad for a stackoverflow question, which should be about programming.